# Chef: Remote File not able to notify Execute or Ruby_Block

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hi Guys I am working on below code snippet. I tried various combinations with I am not able to call **manage_auth** or **authorized_users_ldap** from RemoteFile

I am able to notify **manage_auth** or **authorized_users_ldap** from ruby_block "manage_operator" but not from RemoteFile

I want to trigger either of the 2 (**manage_auth** or **authorized_users_ldap**) if manage_operator_flag is equal to 1. Thus I tried putting a notify on remote_file, but that is not getting triggered. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

```
ruby_block "manage_auth" do
  block do
    Chef::Log.info("MANAGE AUTH")
  end
  action :nothing
end

ruby_block "manage_operator" do
  block do
    manage_operator_flag = (cfg.fetch("manage.operators", 0) == 1)
    if (manage_operator_flag) then
      f =  Chef::Resource::File::RemoteFile.new("#{node['ucms']['dir']}/bin/ucms_authorized_users_ldap.json", run_context)
      f.source "https://ca.#{c}.#{p}.axiadids.net:4443/ucms_authorized_users_ldap.json"
      f.retries 3
      f.retry_delay 10
      f.ignore_failure true
      # f.run_action :create
      f.action :create
      # f.notifies :run, "execute[authorized_users_ldap]"
      # f.notifies(:run, Chef::Resource::Execute.new("authorized_users_ldap", run_context))
      f.notifies :run, "ruby_block[manage_auth]"
    end
  end
end

execute "authorized_users_ldap" do
  command "touch /tmp/test"
  action :nothing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at the `manage_operator` ruby block, you should drop the `then` keyword since there is no such keyword in ruby.

change:

```
if (manage_operator_flag) then
```

to:

```
if (manage_operator_flag)
```

and just like you did in `manage_auth` ruby block, add log output within the condition block.

also, you should definitly execute chef-client with higher verbosity and examine the log. you can do that by appending [`--log_level debug` to chef-client](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options), that is:

```sh
$ chef-client --log_level debug
```

i would also recommend you to use [`remote_file` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) directly, rather then using `ruby_block` to invoke `remote_file` dynamically (at run\convergance-time)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to get inside the **if block**, and fetch remote file, but after fetching of remote_file, it is not able to notify ruby_block[manage_auth]

Comment: @Lavesh: i've updated my answer. please execute chef-client with `debug` log-level, then update your post to include the output. i will try to update my answer accordingly.